# Does every locally compact group G contain a maximal open subgroup P which is a pro-Lie group?

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups

**EDIT 1:** All topological groups in this question are assumed to be second countable. In particular, this forces every group to be metrizable and every Lie group to have at most countably many components. In particular, all discrete groups are countable. The general case (where a Lie group is just assumed to be locally Euclidean and nothing else) could also be interesting, but for this question the second countable case is enough.

First some terminology:

A closed normal subgroup $N$ of a topological group $P$ is *co-Lie* in $P$, if $P/N$ is a (finite dimensional real) Lie group.

A *locally compact pro-Lie group* $P$ is a locally compact group such that every identity neighborhood $U\subseteq P$ contains a subgroup $N$ which is co-Lie in $P$. (This is equivalent to the fact that $P$ is the projective limit of some family of Lie groups.)

Now, there is one version of the famous Gleason-Yamabe theorem which states that
"Every locally compact group $G$ contains an open subgroup $P$ which is a pro-Lie group."

Easy examples show that such a subgroup $P$ is not unique. So, the question arises if there is a maximal one. The obvious thing to try would be to use Zorn's Lemma, but it is not clear to me if the union of a chain of open pro-Lie groups is again a pro-Lie group (it is certainly open, that is not the problem).

Any ideas on this?

**EDIT 2:** Note that in the case where $G$ itself is pro-Lie, it is obvious that there is a maximal open pro-Lie subgroup; just take $G$ itself. This solves the problem for the cases where

- $G$ is abelian
- $G$ is compact
- $G$ is connected (or has a finite number of components),

because in all of these cases it is well-known that $G$ is pro-Lie.

So, if there is a counter-example, it has to be a locally compact group $G$  which is non-abelian, non-compact and has infinitely many components.

Comment: What are the restrictions on the discrete groups that count as Lie groups?  Finite?  Countable?  Arbitrary?

Comment: I think you forgot to assume that your a.bient group is connected (or has countably many components).

Comment: @LSpice: Thanks for asking, I clarified this now.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: I edited the question. The ambient group is not assumed to be connected, because otherwise a question about open subgroups would be boring. I also do not assume that the ambient group has countably many components as many interesting compact groups, like the p-adics have uncountably many components. All Lie groups however have only countably many components (after my edit)

Comment: What happens in the case of a totally disconnected locally compact group, such as the automorphism group of a regular tree (equipped with the permutation topology)?

Comment: @TomDeMedts well, in case you take its simple core: if I'm corrects such a group is compactly generated and all its proper open subgroups are compact. This implies that an subgroup is pro-Lie iff it's compact and every compact open subgroup is contained in a maximal one.

Comment: @YCor: Why are all proper open subgroups of the automorphism group of a regular tree compact? Is that a consequence of the fact that the group is compactly generated? Sorry, if that is obvious... but I don't see it

Comment: @Cosine no, it's not obvious. This is due to the Howe-Moore property. Reference: Alexander Lubotzky, Shahar Mozes. Asymptotic properties of unitary representations of tree automorphisms. In: "Harmonic Analysis and Discrete Potential Theory" (Frascati 1991). Plenum Press, 1992.

Comment: @YCor: Thank you for the explanation. So, this means that for automorphism groups of trees, there is always a maximal pro-Lie group? Do you know if it is easier to look at tdlc  groups, i.e. that every tdlc group contains a maximal open pro-discrete subgroup?

Comment: Wouldn't the additive group of the $p$-adic field $\mathbb Q_p$ be an example? It is an ascending union of compact subgroups isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_p$, but is not pro-Lie.

Comment: @Linus every locally compact abelian group is pro-Lie. For instance $\mathbf{Q}_p$ is the projective limit of the discrete groups $\mathbf{Q}_p/p^n\mathbf{Z}_p$.

Comment: @Cosine indeed I expect that it is enough to look at TDLC groups, and that there are counterexample among them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After thinking about the problem for some time, I came up with a counter-example, so as YCor wrote in his comment, it is indeed true that there is not always a maximal open pro-Lie subgroup.

Let $A$ be a nontrivial compact group, for example $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ or the circle group $\mathbb R /\mathbb Z$. Then the countable power $A^{\mathbb N}$ is also compact. Now let $\Gamma$ be the discrete group of all permutations on $\mathbb N$ with finite support. It is clear that $\Gamma$ acts on $A^{\mathbb N}$ by permuting coordinates, so we may form the semi-direct product:

$$ G := A^{\mathbb N} \rtimes \Gamma  $$

which is a locally compact group as a product of a compact and a discrete group (and tdlc if $A$ is so). It is relatively easy to see that $A^{\mathbb N}$ has no co-Lie subgroups which are $\Gamma$ invariant, so $G$ is not a pro-Lie group.

However, since $\Gamma$ is a countable union of finite permutation groups, $G$ is a countable union of compact groups which are all open in $G$. Compact groups are pro-Lie groups, so we have an increasing sequence of open pro-Lie subgroups which does not have an upper bound. So, there is no maximal open pro-Lie subgroup of $G$.